# How do you set index of a list equal to the index of returned values from a function?

Tags: python

Say, I have the function:

```
def f():

a = randint(-6, 7)
b = randint(-6, 7)

d = (a+b)

if (( d ) > 0):

    c = (-1 * d)

if (( d ) < 0):

    c = (-1 * d)

if (( d ) == 0):

    c = 0

return a, b, c
```

Is it possible to set the index of a list equal to b or c like:

list1[2] = c

or something?

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can

```
nth element of the list = list[n-1]
```

example:
if you want the first element of a list to be "yes".

```
list[0]='yes'
```